# Does crusader's mantle stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin

If 2 people are concentrating on different *crusader's mantle* and standing within the radius does the effect stack with another *crusader's mantle* causing 2d4 instead 1d4?

Comment: @True I've marked this question as a duplicate: I believe the answer to the linked question also answers your question. If you feel there's some distinction between the two that I've missed please edit this question to make that clearer and you can flag it for reopening. Happy gaming!